# hover add class on 2 li's

Tags: jquery, hover, addclass

I've got 2 separate ul lists and when i hover an li in either list it needs to add class hover - and correspond with both lists.

So if i hover over the 1st li in either list i want to add class hover to both li's

If you check out what i got so far. I want it so if you roll over either corresponding item in the list class hover gets added to both li's. Rather than it just adding in 1 place like i have on fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/5Dx58/3/

```
<div class="price-table-container">

<div class="panel-one">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="panel-two">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
    $(".price-table-container .panel-one li, .price-table-container .panel-two li").hover(function() {
$(this).addClass('hover');
    }, function() {
$(this).removeClass('hover'); 
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get `index` of hovered `li` and find according `li` to add/remove class.

```
$(".price-table-container li, .price-table-container .panel-two li").hover(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    $(".price-table-container").find("ul").each(function(){
        $(this).find("li:eq("+index+")").addClass('hover');
    });
        }, function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    $(".price-table-container").find("ul").each(function(){
        $(this).find("li:eq("+index+")").removeClass('hover');
    });
});
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Dx58/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to solve the problem where we specifically:

- Grab the current `li`'s index number
- Grab the hovered panel's class name
- Specifically update the other panel's corresponding `li` element
- Removing the hover class is easier - remove it from all `li` elements at once

`->`<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Dx58/5/)</kbd>`<-`

```
var ndx, ol, $this;
$(".price-table-container .panel-one li, .price-table-container .panel-two li").hover(
    function() {
        $this = $(this);
        ndx = $this.index();
        ol = ($this.parent().parent().attr('class') == 'panel-one') ? 'panel-two' : 'panel-one';

        $this.addClass('hover');
        $('.'+ol).find('li:eq(' +ndx+ ')').addClass('hover')
    }, 
    function() {
        $('li').removeClass('hover'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly shorter version

```
$(".price-table-container .panel-one li, .price-table-container .panel-two li").hover(function() {
    var index = $(this).index() + 1;
    $('.price-table-container li:nth-child(' + index + ')').addClass('hover');
        }, function() {
    var index = $(this).index() + 1;
    $('.price-table-container li:nth-child(' + index + ')').removeClass('hover');;
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Dx58/6/)